# Como pegar os dados de um campo especifico em um XML usando LINQ VB.net/C#

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq

Eu tenho o sequinte xml:

```
<det nItem="1">
    <prod>
        <cProd>01554</cProd>
        <xProd>La Aslan Velour 0001 </xProd>
        <NCM>55111000</NCM>
        <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
        <uCom>UN</uCom>
        <qCom>1.0000</qCom>
        <vUnCom>6.90</vUnCom>
        <indRegra>A</indRegra>
    </prod>
    <imposto>
        <ICMS>
            <ICMSSN102>
                <Orig>0</Orig>
                <CSOSN>102</CSOSN>
            </ICMSSN102>
        </ICMS>
    </imposto>
 </det>
```

Tenho um loop que valida meus produtos, ele verifica os impostos e 
retornar um erro caso o imposto estiver incorreto.
Se caso acontecer de aparecer um produto com o imposto incorreto eu preciso saber qual é, para isso uso um contador no loop, mas como posso fazer para pegar os dados do item?

Os itens incia com um `<det nItem="1">`, o que vai mudar é o numero que vai indicar o item, mas como posso apontar o meu contador para pegar os dados que estão dentro do `<det nItem="1">` ?

Segue o código até então:

```vb
'Loop de todos os ICMS dos produtos
For Each ReadXML In document.Descendants("ICMS")

    'Contador de produtos
     Contador_Prod += 1

       dim Prod = ReadXML.Descendants.Attributes(Contador_Prod)

 Next
```

Pensei que eu teria que usar o `Attributes`, mas não deu muito certo.

Comment: Tentou isto? http://stackoverflow.com/a/594243/221800 veja do lado outras perguntas semelhantes. Outro http://stackoverflow.com/a/1431775/221800 Se for isso, eu posso por uma resposta.

Comment: Então, não cheguei a ver, mas ainda não ajuda, pois o valor entre aspas duplas, será diferente para cada item, mas será sequencial.
Acontece que tenho que verificar o ICMS primeiro e depois o produto se caso for preciso.
Minha ideia foi usar o contador para apontar, pois na realidade preciso do conteúdo do <prod>

Comment: È que eu não entendi bem o que você quer mas é questão de dar uma pequena adaptada. Ou então você LINQ ou qualquer forma de varrer o XML diretamente.

Comment: Então, após da leitura do ICMS, tenho um função que verifica se o ICMS é valido, caso não for, eu preciso identificar em qual produto do XML o ICMS está incorreto, mas como eu disse os produtos tem uma sequencia, que é determinada pelo nItem=" " , ex: Produto 1 = <det nItem="1">, produto 2 =  <det nItem="2">
Caso o produto 2 estiver com o ICMS incorreto, eu preciso dos dados do <det nitem="2">

Comment: Existe alguma possibilidade de eu apontar qual nItem eu preciso ? 
Por exemplo tenho 10 itens, quero o item 6, como posso apontar o nItem="6" ? 
Isso já iria me ajudar.

Comment: @FelipeWalleg. Tente importar como "uma tabela", assim você poderá utilizar comando de consulta e comparação, looping e etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each tagICMS As XmlNode In document.GetElementsByTagName("ICMS"))
  Dim tagImposto As XmlNode = tagICMS.ParentNode 
  Dim tagDet As XmlNode = tagImposto.ParentNode
  Dim attribNItem As XmlAttribute = tagDet.Attributes("nItem")
  Dim nrDetalheAtual = CInt(attribNItem.Value)
Next
```

*Obs: Não acho que essa seja a melhor fluxo para o que você precisa. Esta é apenas uma resposta direta ao que você perguntou - reconsidere iterar da mesma maneira como o Xml está estruturado: Ler Cabeçalho da NF, depois itens, depois detalhes dos itens, etc - sempre mantendo a memória (estado) da hierarquia*